# Django form for adding emails connected to models

Tags: python, django

This is a bit hard to explain but I'll try my best.

I am developing a website where I want a feature where the admins can add an email notification connected to a certain model. The admin should be able to

1. Choose a model on the website,
2. What event it should trigger on (`create`, `update` or `delete`),
3. The email body and text.

For example, if the admin adds an email to a model `foo` on a `create` event, the specified email should be sent to some recipient whenever a new `foo` is added to the database.

I am attempting to implement a new model that contains some reference to the models, using `post_save()` to send emails, but it's turning out more complex than I thought. I have searched far and wide to find some addon that does this, but I haven't found any.

Does anyone have any tips on specific functionalities that can help with this, or if there's a good addon that I can start with?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model (called "SendEmail" for example) that contain the relations and the data of the emails is a good idea. May be you can override save and delete methods on the other models. In your views, before save or delete an object, check in your new model "SendEmail" if it is necessary to send and email and pass this object to the save/delete method.

In your views, after check, if you have to send the email:

```
foo.save(sendemail=sendemail) #where sendemail is a SendEmail object.
```

if not:

```
foo.save()
```

In your existing models:

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
   ----
   ----
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs, sendemail=None):
       if sendemail:
           **the code to send the email**
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

EDIT:

To not override all de save method for all your models you can create a new model class with the save method and change the class of your actual models:

```
Class SendEmailModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs, sendemail=None):
        if sendemail:
            **the code to send the email**
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.

Class Foo(SendEmailModel):
    ----
    ----
```

Comment: That might work in a pinch. It's not as flexible as I want it, since I need to add this to every model that might require an email sendout.

Comment: Ok, I have modified the answer to get closer to your request.

Comment: This might work, but it's not as flexible as I want it to be. I don't want to check for `sendemail` everytime the model is saved, I want a separate model to always send an email for every connected model.